# Explanation of CAVP format for NIST Test Vectors for SHA-2 and 3

Tags: sha-256, sha-2, nist, test-vectors

I want to run the SHA2 and SHA3 NIST algorithm test vectors provided in the zip files at the bottom of this page:
http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/secure-hashing.html#sha-2

I don't quite understand how the test vectors are encoded. For example, if I run the SHA2-256 algorithm on an empty string as so:

```
import hashlib
sha2_256_test_str = b""
sha2_standard = hashlib.sha256(sha2_256_test_str).hexdigest()
```

I obtain the hash:

```
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

Which is correct. However, if I look at the first test vector in the NIST zip file it says that:

```
#  CAVS 11.0
#  "SHA-256 ShortMsg" information
#  SHA-256 tests are configured for BYTE oriented implementations
#  Generated on Tue Mar 15 08:23:38 2011

[L = 32]

Len = 0
Msg = 00
MD = e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

This would seem to indicate to me that for a message of "00", I should receive the hash above. However, this is the hash I obtain for an empty string. So for instance, the way that I interpret to run this test vector in Python is:

```
import hashlib
sha2_256_test_str = b"00"
sha2_standard = hashlib.sha256(sha2_256_test_str).hexdigest()
```

But this gives the hash

```
f1534392279bddbf9d43dde8701cb5be14b82f76ec6607bf8d6ad557f60f304e
```

What key point am I missing here? How would I be able to convert the messages in the NIST zip files to a message for my Python script?

Comment: Well, actually they are specifying the length of the input string you should consider and in your case it is 0 bit long, so it is not the string "00", which is 8 bits long, but the empty string "", which is the only one of length 0.

Comment: Not sure why they used Msg = 00, but Len = 0 clearly means that they're hashing the empty string.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense to me. For instance, what about the next test vector that has `Len = 1` and `Msg = 00`. The hash they give isn't obtained for that message nor for anything obvious. How can I interpret these vectors more generally?

Comment: You will likely need a bit aligned hash function.

Comment: @back_seat_driver Could you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: A bit aligned hash implementation is one that can hash arbitrary bit strings, such as a string that consists of 1 bit; that's what `Len=1` is asking for.  If your implementation can only hash byte strings, then you'll want to look at the 'byte oriented' test vectors.

Answer (score 5):

All of your questions are answered in the Validation System documents that are linked to by the algorithm test pages.  In this case, look at http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/shs/SHAVS.pdf

For this case, the message length is expressed in bits not bytes. The fact that the message is also encoded as value of `00` should be ignored in the test vectors smaller than one byte; this just adds confusion to the reader.

Len = The length of a message in bits

Answer (score 0):

Your hash is `f1534392279bddbf9d43dde8701cb5be14b82f76ec6607bf8d6ad557f60f304e` because b'00' is parsed as a string.

The NIST specification is correct: SHA256 with a zero length argument should always result in `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`

It may also help to know that with one single byte set to zero, the hash is `6e340b9cffb37a989ca544e6bb780a2c78901d3fb33738768511a30617afa01d`

Comment: Listing the test vectors here is not really what was asked for, it asked for an *explanation* why the tests failed and how the CAVP test vectors are formatted. The question title may have misled you.